# Troubled with making a PHP db driven multiple choice Quiz

Tags: php, mysql

So my objective sounds simple, I need to make a db driven multiple choice quiz 
CMS to add into my project. I need to be able to create quizzes by category, add 10 questions per quiz, and 4 questions with 1 answer. I've been troubled in 2 areas.

1. Database structure. How can I structure my database so that I can do this? eg, a table for each questions, question_answers, and quizzes?
2. After the users takes the quiz, I want to grab the score and store it into its own table. I know how to put the score into the database, but how would I display the quiz, with the corresponding question, with the corresponding answers, and the correct answer with the right radio button?

It's very tricky to me, but maybe not to some of you geniuses out there.

Best regards,

Sean

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow was created for developers to get answers to very specific questions. Your question sounds like you just want someone to write all the code for you.

Comment: Sean - you should provide sample code that you have tried so far and address significant problems and issues you are encountering. Do not expect someone to make the work for you and give an complete solution.

Comment: I do not want someone to make code for me at all. All I need to know, for example, is a breakdown of my problem. Almost no code is needed for my answer. The problem is thinking out the problem. I generally don't write code until I know how I'm going to go about it. Let me give you something for an example. 
Sean - For the first part you can combine two of the tables by doing ______. It saves you time and it is easier in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicked this table structure for you. The foreign key constraints are optional.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answer` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `answer` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `question_id` (`question_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `question` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `quiz_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `question` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `correct_anwer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `quiz_id` (`quiz_id`,`correct_anwer_id`),
  KEY `correct_anwer_id` (`correct_anwer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `quiz` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

ALTER TABLE `answer`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `answer_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `question`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `question_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`correct_anwer_id`) REFERENCES `answer` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `question_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`quiz_id`) REFERENCES `quiz` (`id`);
```

And for storing the test, users have taken:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `quiz_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_taken` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `score` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `quiz_id` (`quiz_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_answer` (
  `test_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `question_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `answer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `single_score` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_id`,`question_id`),
  KEY `question_id` (`question_id`),
  KEY `answer_id` (`answer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

ALTER TABLE `test`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `test_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`quiz_id`) REFERENCES `quiz` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `test_answer`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `test_answer_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`answer_id`) REFERENCES `answer` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `test_answer_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`test_id`) REFERENCES `test` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `test_answer_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`);
```

Some sample data to play around:

```
INSERT INTO `answer` (`id`, `question_id`, `answer`) VALUES
(3, 1, 'stackoverflow.com '),
(4, 1, 'example.com');

INSERT INTO `question` (`id`, `quiz_id`, `question`, `correct_anwer_id`) VALUES
(6, 1, 'What is the best website on the whole internet?', 3);

INSERT INTO `quiz` (`id`, `category`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 1337, 'My Great Quiz. Take me!');
```

Comment: This is what I had in mind. Now when the user answers the question, would I see if he has the right answer by comparing the radio to the answers table?

Comment: The correct answer is saved as a reference in the column `question.correct_answer_id`. Since every question has only one correct answer (my assumption), I stored it in the `question` table.

Comment: Thanks! I think I've got it now